# при нажатии на елемент, activom появлялось сразу два

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток. У нас есть форма, с двумя инпутами, и нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку поиска появлялся второй инпут с полем ввода текста. Т.е. первый инпут мы выделяем фокусом, он меняется, и нужно чтобы еще одновременно менялся и второй.  Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такое сделать?

```css
.search_form>input:nth-child(1) {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: url(../images/search.png) no-repeat center top 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 33px 53px 0 0;
}

.search_form>input:focus {
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  background: url(../images/search.png) #535353 no-repeat center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 24px 53px 24px 0;
}
```

```html
`
<form class="search_form" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="request" value="">
  <input type="search" name="#" value="" placeholder="Найти информацию ...">
</form>`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 10 раз перечитываю,ни фига не понял...

Comment: Добавил два изображения. На первом ничего не происходит. Мы нажимаем на кнопку, и  появляеться поле поиска.

Comment: Тебе люди помогают, а ты даже не хочешь принять ответ,  три вопроса с ответами и не одного  принятого, не красиво...

Comment: Вижу только один ответ. Все это время был не в сети, поэтому никак не реагировал.  И я очень благодарен людям за помощь. Спасибо вам огромное)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

стили думаю сами исправите

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input');

input.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.offsetX < 51) {
    input.value = '';
  }

})
input.addEventListener('input', function(event) {
  if (input.value !== '') {
    document.querySelector('button').className = 'button';
  }
})
input.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.offsetX < 51) {
    input.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  } else {
    input.style.cursor = 'text';
  }
})
```

```css
@import "http://fonts.fontstorage.com/import/adventpro.css";
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #065b79;
  overflow: auto;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: url(http://www.countryporch.com/icons/search.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Advent';
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 0 solid #fff;
  transition: all .4s;
}

input:focus {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 400px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  background-color: grya;
  background-image: url(http://nouveal.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable-nouveal/img/croix@2x.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Advent';
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: .1px solid #fff;
  transition: all .4s;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  background-color: grya;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Advent';
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: .1px solid #fff;
  transition: all .4s;
}

button.button {
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  padding-left: 55px;
  background-color: grya;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Advent';
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: .1px solid #fff;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

```html
`
<form class="search_form" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="#" value="" placeholder="Найти информацию ...">
  <button>Жми</button>
</form>`
```